# How to view the static content of a Thymeleaf fragment without rewriting it again where it is used?

Tags: thymeleaf

So the title is the question.. I have a fragment like

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" th:fragment="header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Shop</a>
```

So when i open this file in a browser, the static content (e.g. My Shop) will be displayed.

On the main html file where i import this part, i just want to use a simple th:replace tag like this:

```
<div th:replace="fragments :: header"></div>
```

So, at runtime, everything works fine. But when i want to use this file also for prototyping, opening the file directly in a browser, the contents of the file (static text like "My Shop") will not be displayed, since this file does not know anything about the fragment. Is there any way of achieving this, without rewriting all the contents also in the main html?

I can imagine sth like this:

```
<div th:replace="fragments :: header" th:fragment-file="fragment.html"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Thymeleaf doc (http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/layouts.html)

> When a Thymeleaf template is used as a static prototype, we cannot see
>   the fragments we are including using the th:include/th:replace host
>   tags. We can only see the fragments aside, opening their own template
>   documents.
>
> However, there is a way to see the real fragments included into our
>   pages while prototyping. This can be done using Thymol
>   (http://www.thymoljs.org/), an unofficial JavaScript library that is
>   an implementation of Thymeleaf’s standard fragment inclusion
>   functionality, providing static support for some Thymeleaf attributes
>   like th:include or th:replace, conditional display with
>   th:if/th:unless, etc.

You could also use a template alias (using resolver.addTemplateAlias("template", "folder/template"))