# How to set up Thymeleaf templated pages to be viewed and edited by web designer?

Tags: thymeleaf

I've set up a website using Thymealeaf as a template manager. Each page includes a template, which later includes the content.

Here's the template.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  th:fragment="loggedout">
<head th:include="components/meta :: head" /> 
<body>
    <div th:include="components/meta :: js" />   
    <div th:include="components/header :: loggedin" />
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="content">
                <div th:include="this ::content" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer th:include="components/footer :: basic" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the javascript and css are included from other places.

Here's an example of a web page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      th:include="components/layout :: loggedin">
    <div th:fragment="content">
        <h1>download</h1>
        <br></br>
        <p>You can download the installer here! Make sure to check out the <a href="getting-started"> getting started page</a>.</p>
        <br></br>
        <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary " type="submit">download</button>
    </div>
</html>
```

So, the problem is that there is no way to view the website without running the app in a servlet container, a situation that I'd prefer to avoid if possible. Is there any way to make it easier for my designer to view and alter this website? Alternatively, is there a technology to specifically address this problem? I've done a good amount of searching to no avail.

Comment: Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27476981/4316870

Comment: Thank you patrick, that's something I must have missed in my search.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view the static content of a Thymeleaf fragment without rewriting it again where it is used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473622/how-to-view-the-static-content-of-a-thymeleaf-fragment-without-rewriting-it-agai)